# Can I have a MYSQL table that automatically feeds off of 2 or more tables in the same database?

Tags: mysql, join, report

Can I create a table that automatically pulls all data from existing tables? I know that there's "UNION ALL", but I want to create a table that's its own entity – not just for queries.

Is this only possible in reports or can I have this new table automatically update when I add new data to the existing tables?

If not, can someone recommend good report generating software that can do this well and works on OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29). [Here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) how to create views in MySQL. A View lets you create a "virtual" table that can pull data from other database tables. Then you can get the data from the View as if it was it's own table (even though it's an aggregate of other tables). Any changes to the underlying data will cause the view to be updated as well.

Comment: thank you! this sounds perfect. one more question - do you know of a mac software that does this outside of queries? right now I use Sequel Pro, but according to this: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sequel-pro/0csAmVi8gJQ) sequel pro's interface doesn't support the direct creation of views

Comment: I don't know any off the top of my head, sorry. You can try Navicat, but I don't know if it supports this either.

Answer (score 2):

It is a view that you are looking for, not another table. It is essentially a saved `SELECT` query.

```
CREATE VIEW {my_view}
AS
SELECT ...
```